# Как сфотографировать Here map?

Tags: java, android, map

В проекте использую Here map-android-sdk. Нужно сфотографировать экран с картой, в sdk нужного функционала не нашёл. Знаю, что для google map работает [вот это решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309625/how-can-i-take-merge-screen-shot-of-google-map-v2-and-layout-of-xml-both-program). При попытке сфотографировать родительскую вьюху в которой лежит карта, вместо карты получается чёрная область. Кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Есть какие-то идеи?

Код которым пытаюсь сделать скрин ниже:

```
View screenView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    Bitmap bitmapFull = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getWidth(), screenView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmapFull = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapFull, 0, 0, screenView.getWidth(), screenView.getHeight());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapFull);
    screenView.draw(canvas);
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: принт скрин экрана телефона не подойдет?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду, тот же способ который описан у меня в коде?

Comment: Скрин экрана, нажать одновременно клавишу питания и громкости. Но как я понял, это немного не то, что вам нужно

Comment: очень много лишнего кода с размерами, можно просто получить размеры нужного view элемента и сделать bitmap вывести в канву также

Comment: Да, исправил, но проблема не решена

Comment: Вот какой-то вариант с запуском из кода adb комманды: [тык](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27919046/3212712)

Comment: На 5-м андроиде не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем ответ такой:

> Note: The MapFragment class provides an asynchronous method,
>   `getScreenCapture(OnScreenCaptureListener)`, for creating map snapshots
>   of the currently visible MapFragment area. When a snapshot has been
>   created, an event callback to `OnScreenCaptureListener` occurs, and the
>   screenshot is provided as an android.graphics.Bitmap object. This
>   method of screen capture only works if the view is in the foreground
>   and it is rendering. If a background or viewless screen capture is
>   required, use MapOffscreenRenderer.

Но это работает только для premium версии sdk.